# Scroll horizontally recycleview with smoothScrollToPosition not work

Tags: android

I get trouble with scroll recycle.
Here is my LinearlayoutManager:

```
public class LayoutManagerCustom  extends LinearLayoutManager {
private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 50f;
private Context mContext;

public LayoutManagerCustom(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
}

public LayoutManagerCustom(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    this.mContext = context;
}



@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                   final RecyclerView.State state, final int position) {

    LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller =
            new LinearSmoothScroller(mContext) {

                //This controls the direction in which smoothScroll looks
                //for your view
                @Override
                public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition
                (int targetPosition) {
                    return LayoutManagerCustom.this
                            .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
                }

                //This returns the milliseconds it takes to
                //scroll one pixel.
                @Override
                protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel
                (DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                    return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH/displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                }
            };
    smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
}


@Override
public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    return super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state);

}
```

}

And here is my code to create RecycleView:

```
 layoutManager = new LayoutManagerCustom(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    recyclerViewItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    recyclerViewItem.setAdapter(recycleViewItemAdapter);
    params.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerViewItem, new RecyclerView.State(),Constant.NUM_DATE/2);
```

With debug mode, i saw

> computeScrollVectorForPosition

will be called if create layoutManager with VERTICAL but with HORIZONTAL it is not called.

And here is example about this:
[Customizing SmoothScroller for the RecyclerView](https://mcochin.wordpress.com/2015/05/13/android-customizing-smoothscroller-for-the-recyclerview/)

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

If the view of smooth scroll target is near enough from initial position, the computeScrollVectorForPosition method will not be called.

Dose the target view become near by creating layoutManager with HORIZONTAL?
If so, you can change the speed like this:

```
public class LayoutManagerCustom  extends LinearLayoutManager {

    private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH_FOR_DECELERATION = 500f;

    ...

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                       final RecyclerView.State state, final int position) {

        LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller =
                new LinearSmoothScroller(mContext) {

                    @Override
                    protected int calculateTimeForDeceleration(int dx) {
                        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                        float MILLISECONDS_PER_PX = MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH_FOR_DECELERATION / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                        int time = (int) Math.ceil(Math.abs(dx) * MILLISECONDS_PER_PX);
                        return  (int) Math.ceil(time / .3356);
                    }

                    ...

                };
        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override more two methods for your CustomLinearLayoutManager class.

```
public class LayoutManagerCustom  extends LinearLayoutManager {

//All your code above here...

//        For Vertical scroll
        @Override
        protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
            return SNAP_TO_START;
        }

//        For Horizontal scroll
        @Override
        protected int getHorizontalSnapPreference() {
            return SNAP_TO_START;
        }
}
```